# Python Sum of all subset of list using list comprehension and recursion

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

I'm trying to write a program that returns set of all subset sum of a list. I must use list comprehension and recursion.

Example:

```
[1,2,3,10]
return set([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,100,101,102,103,104,105,106])
```

I write code:

```
def function(L):
    if len(L) == 0:
        return []
    return list((L[index] + rest) for index in range(len(L)) for rest in function(L[:index])+L[index+1:])
```

This code returns sum of subsets but only 2 or more elemental subset.
Example
[1,2,3,4,100]
return [3,4,5,6,101,102,103,104,105,106]

Comment: Is there some big programming assignment for a course? I've seen this question at least 3 times in the past 2 days.

Comment: Yes this is a part from a course but it isn`t part of bigger problem.

Comment: Could you edit the last sentence in your current question. "set of sum but without sum of one or no element"?

Comment: Program don`t consider 0 and 1 element subset

Comment: So there are no 1 element or 0 element subset sums in your result right?

Comment: Yes, this is a problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is change that seems to yield the right answer:

```
def function(L):
 if len(L) == 0:return []
 return L+list((L[index] + rest) for index in range(len(L)) for rest in function(L[:index])+L[index+1:])
```